# subscribe() to the same stream in 2 different components in Angular 2 with rxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to setup a login in a Ionic 2 web application and I'm using observables.

I have an auth module with a login method, which connects to the remote database to log the user; if the login is successful I want to store the token (auth0) in the localstorage

So this is in my auth.service.ts

```
login(user: any) {
    this.http
      .get(SERVER_URL, { user_data }, options)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => this.authSuccess(data.jwt),
        err => this.handleError(err));
  }
```

So, this is working fine on its own. Now I want to use a login screen, so when the user submit the data, if the login is successful the app will navigate to the main screen, otherwise will display an error message.

The login component should have something like this

```
loginUser(event) {
    return this.authService
      .login(event.user)
      .subscribe(
        data => navigate_to_main,
        err => display_error_and_stay_in_login);
  }
```

So, I need to subscribe in the login method within the service because I only want to store the token if the login is successful, but I also need to subscribe in the loginUser method inside the LoginComponent to navigate only if the login was successful.

How is this done? Maybe I'm not doing this the proper way.

Anyone can help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

auth.service.ts could return the observable, allowing login component to do the subscription:

```
login(user: any) {
    return this.http
      .get(SERVER_URL, { user_data }, options)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .do(
        data => this.authSuccess(data.jwt),
        err => this.handleError(err));
  }
```

If you need to call login from multiple places, you could avoid repeated requests using .cache:

```
private _login$;

loginOnce(user: any) {
    if (!this._login) {
        this._login = this.loginUser(user).cache();
    }
    return this._login;
}
```

Usage from component:

```
this.authService.login(user).subscribe(response => ...)
```

Comment: It should be noted that you need  to subscribe in order to consume the data. In fact, I recently noticed the HTTP request will not be executed until someone subscribes to it.

Comment: @Luftzig. Yes. And this is true of ANY observable, not just those containing HTTP requests. Observables are like functions. They're not executed unless they are invoked, or "subscribed" in the case of observables.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same by making below change in your `auth.service.ts`:

```
login(user: any) {
  return this.http
    .get(SERVER_URL, { user_data }, options)
    .map((response: Response) => {
      let data = response.json();
      this.authSuccess(data.jwt)
      return data;
    });
}
```

Comment: but then I'm missing the chance to handle the error in my AuthService, right?

Comment: This works, but the semantics are wrong. `map` is used for mapping a value in the observable, not for doing side-effects. `do` is semantically appropriate for side effects.

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe only when you want to consume the data. You can handle error in service with `catch`.

You will have to import it  `import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';`

```
login(user: any) {
  return this.http
    .get(SERVER_URL, { user_data }, options)
    .map((response: Response) => {
      let data = response.json();
      this.authSuccess(data.jwt)
      return data;
    }).catch((err) => this.handleError(err) )
}
```